# Saving SVG element points in the database

Tags: database, svg, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

We are developing a drawer SVG based. The user can add elements to it and so on. The elements of the SVG  have theirs points saved in the database. When the application loads, the SVG is drawn properly. Here it works fine!

Now the user can move elements around and rotate them. Once those actions are made, the new points of the elements should be sent to the database. The problem with this is that using `transform` we are changing the user coordinate system and with that the points of all other elements.

My first thought was to iterate throughout all the SVG elements and update their points when the points of one single element changes.

What is the best practice when working with SVG?

Comment: I don't know which is the best practice. But you can write a function that recalculate the new position of the points. For example I've written a function that recalculate the new position of the translated path, but you may need to take in consideration the rotation too. I think this is what illustrator does although I'm not very sure.